# How is PDF.js getTextContent returning multiple character strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf.js

PDF.js getTextContent() is returning string values of *multiple characters* at times and I'm trying to discern why that is.

I've been regularly crawling 90+ page pdfs getting text content with PDF.js with 99% of results being broken down into their individual characters (thank you Mozilla).

```
  let doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(name).promise;
  let numPages = doc.numPages;


  let lines = [];
 let index = 0;
 for (var pageNum = 1; pageNum <= numPages; pageNum++) {
let pageData = await doc.getPage(pageNum);

let viewport = pageData.getViewport(1);
console.log(viewport)
let pageBase = (numPages - pageNum) * 2000;
let pageHeight = (viewport.viewBox[3])
let pageWidth = viewport.viewBox[2]

let yArr = []
let textContent = await pageData.getTextContent();
*** Then we do some callback stuff with text  - works fine ***
```

textContent USUALLY looks like this[image: 99% of data has a 'str' value of a single character]

Recently ran into a bug and I realized that some strings are coming in longer - usually page numbers[image]
see index 497

once again after running a filter
[image]

I'm really looking to acertain what exactly is causing some of these strings to register with PDF.js as multi-characters strings when the majority are single.  I'd hate for this thing to surprise me down the road in a way I can't anticipate.

PDF.js: v2.6.347
Node.js v12.18.2

Debugging in VSCode:
Version: 1.52.1
Electron: 9.3.5
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0

Thanks!

Comment: Part of this has to do with the fact that PDF's are basically image and vector collections. That coherent text exists at all in them is due to demand. While the text in your examples may usually be broken out per character, this isn't required. In fact, it would be more convenient if it was grouped by chunk. As far as pdf.js is concerned, it's just reading out the raw text fragments as they're presented in the PDF file structure.

Comment: So I guess theres no  telling why this may be happening?

Comment: It's just how PDFs are put together. The software used to assemble the PDF would also have some effect.

Comment: Interesting thanks for the input.